# How do i pinch to zoom on a Listbox Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, zooming, windows-phone, pinchzoom

I have a **databound listbox** but the text font inside the template is a bit small for the case since the Listbox have 4 textblocks in it. This is all(textbox) aligned in a horizontal way since it display short information. I have the text wrapped also. **My question is**, is there a possible way to make a pinch to zoom at the listbox level or is this even possible in the phone at all. I've seen **adobe reader pinch to zoom and it suck at it**. I've looked up at some reference but all point to zooming at a picture. Here are the link I've read so far and kind of understood.

http://www.frenk.com/2011/03/windows-phone-7-correct-pinch-zoom-in-silverlight/ 
[Pinch to Zoom on ListBox on windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491126/pinch-to-zoom-on-listbox-on-windows-phone-7/) 
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/72968/445310.aspx

**Until now I have not implemented any code prior to the pinch to zoom.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach a `GestureListener` to the `ListBox` to detect the Pinch gesture.

Then according to your Pinch gesture, you have to modify the `RenderTransform` property of your `ListBox`.

It is easiest if you assign a `CompositeTransform` to the `RenderTransform` property for that matter.